# Spring Query - check number of rows in DB

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot

I have the following method in my Spring Boot app in my Repository:

```
@Query("""
            SELECT tw FROM TW tw
            INNER JOIN tw.docks d // TW entity has list of docks
            WHERE d.id = :dockId
            AND tw.status <> 'DELETED'
            """)
List<TW> findAllTWs(long dockId);
```

How to check if TW has exactly one dock (tw.docks.size() == 1)? I have to filter out tw.docks with more than 1 dock (I want only list of TWs with one dock)
Probably I need native query for that

Comment: off the top of my head, I think you basically have 2 options, either check docks.size() in your code or use select count(*). If you use select count(*) and get 1, you'll need a second query to return the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `SIZE` function which is valid in `jpql` language.

```
@Query("""
            SELECT tw FROM TW tw
            INNER JOIN tw.docks d // TW entity has list of docks
            WHERE d.id = :dockId
            AND tw.status <> 'DELETED' AND SIZE(tw.docks) = 1
            """)
```

Comment: But this solution is better, with tw.docks.size I get WARN: syntax in HQL/JPQL query [tw.ramps.size]; use collection function syntax instead [size(tw.docks)].

Answer (score 1):

This should generate sql with a subquery:

```
SELECT tw 
FROM TW tw 
WHERE tw.docks.size = 1
```

See the appended documentation, size is a special HQL property.

---

See:  [HQL docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: @Matley just a note here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html `The Hibernate Query Language (HQL) and Java Persistence Query Language (JPQL) are both object model focused query languages similar in nature to SQL. JPQL is a heavily-inspired-by subset of HQL. A JPQL query is always a valid HQL query, the reverse is not true however.` `SIZE` is part of JPQL

Comment: `HQL` is only for Hibernate while you might switch to EclipseLink or some other provider in future that comply with the general `JPQL`.